# OpenPoup.NET - find email, subject and date from forwarded message - C#

Tags: c#, regex, email-parsing

I am using OpenPoup.NET to read email from Gmail. I want to identify original sender, receiver, date and subject of forwarded message. My email looks like,

> ----------------------Email Body starts-----------------------------------
>
> FYI, read below email to get idea of button.
>
> Chirag Developer XYZ Limited
>
> From: Rat Chanra [mailto:rat@chanra.com]  Sent: Friday, June 5, 2015
>   9:48 PM To: Chirag Subject: FW: Copy Product Button
>
> Hi Rat,
>
> I have included a .png of the copy product button. Attached also is an
>   .eps of updated buttons if we feel like updating all the buttons!
>
> Let's chat,
>
> Ali Designer
>
> ----------------------Email Body Ends-----------------------------------

I want to find From, Date, Sublect and To of original message, which is in this case,

```
From = rat@chanra.com
Date = Friday, June 5, 2015 9:48 PM
To = Chirag
Subject = FW: Copy Product Button
```

Can I do this using OpenPopUp.net?

Do I have to parse email body using RegEx and fetch above detail. If yes, what is best way for that? I am using C#

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
From:\s+[^[]+\s+\[mailto:([^\]]+)\]\s+Sent:\s+(\w+,\s+\w+\s+\d+,\s+\d{4}\s+[\d:]+\s+[aApP]M)\s+To:\s+(\w+)\s+Subject:\s+(.*)
```

And extract `From` as `$1`, `Date` as `$2`, `To` as `$3` and `Subject` as `$4`.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xL4tD3/2)